# execlp() in C doesn't give prompt back after execution

Tags: terminal, exec, fork, prompt

I try to *fork()* a child which will run an `ls` command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    if (fork()==0){ //child
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", (char*)0);
        exit(1);
    }

    fflush(stderr); //doesn't fix my problem
    fflush(stdout); //doesn't fix my problem
    exit(0);
}
```

This works fine but the cursor gets stuck after the execution of the child. I have to press the enter key to get back the terminal. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Your main process exits before the child process is done. Wait for the child process to exit using wait() or waitpid().

Comment: How can I get the status of child, if parent & child exited? Do I need to use waitpid? When & where I can use it?